# firebase dynamic link not matching whitelist regex

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

is it maybe a matter of time? its been over an hour

i do have the regex in the whitelist and a regex test

am i missing anything? ty

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your regex matches this string `https://about.2i2i.app/user/vtxS`. Isn't it supposed to match this `https://about.2i2i.app?uid=8w4s...`?

Comment: it matches both

Comment: `app(\/.*)` in your regex would match a string of this nature: `app/...`. It won't match `app?...`. Therefore, your regex won't match this: `https://about.2i2i.app?uid=8w4s...`. I used `https://regex101.com` to test this.

Comment: yes, fixed it ~ i thought i saw both match, but you were right, the ? was missing ~ ty ~ if you like, add an answer, i can accept it

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches this string `https://about.2i2i.app/user/vtxS`. It would not match this `https://about.2i2i.app?uid=8w4s...`.

`app(\/.*)` in your regex would match a string of this nature: `app/...`. It won't match `app?...`. Therefore, your regex won't match this: `https://about.2i2i.app?uid=8w4s...`.

I used [regex101](https://regex101.com) to test.